# Clearing a Sudoku table

Tags: java, swing, methods, jbutton, sudoku

I'm working on this piece of code which can be found at

http://pastebin.com/7bCFtUHL

Basically, I want to add a clear method (button) which clears the sudoku after having it solved. 
I've tried making a loop that goes through every cell and puts it to null but I'm not completely sure how to connect it exactly. Nor am I sure in which class I'd have to create it so it can be connected to the GUI where I have the other button.

EDIT: 
This is the clear method I currently got

```
public void clearCells(){
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            cells[y][x] = null;
            cells[y][x].setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to attach that to the JButton in another class, how would that be possible?

My clear button looks like this

```
JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");

clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Code                    
    }        
    }
);
```

What code would I need to add in the actionPerformed method to connect it with my clearCells method?

Comment: Please post your pertinent code here in the question. If the code is too large to post here, then it's too large to ask volunteers to slog through.

Comment: just iterate through the **cells** elements and set the empty value of each of them

Comment: aljesco I tried that, to loop through the cells in an ActionListener for the button. But I cant reach the cells from that other class.

Comment: @BobSmith: then give the class that holds the cells a public method, say called `clearCells()`, that has access to the cells, that iterates through the cell collection or array and clears them, and that other classes can call. But again, please post your code *here* before this question gets closed.

Comment: Thank you Hovercraft. I made an edit to my main post

Answer (score 3):

Again, I would put the "meat" of the clear method in the model itself. The general form of a solution would be to do this:

```
clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       myModel.clearCells();
  }
});
```

Where the Model class would have a public `void clearCells()` method that iterates through the cells and clears them.

---

**Edit 1**
Note: yeah I did look at your pastebin code link and one big problem I see is that your SwingSudokuBoard class extends the SudokuBoard class, and this is misuse of inheritance where you should be using *composition* instead. The SwingSudokuBoard class should hold an *instance* of a SudokuBoard object and call methods on it.

---

**Edit 2**
You ask:

> I'm not sure that I can completely understand you. You want me to have the clear method in the same class as I got the button, but then I cant call the cells. I added x.clearCells(); while x being what? My main class like, SwingSudokuBoard.clearCells(); ? Eitherway, if I add what you say the program complaints that it want the clearCells method and cells to be static. But if I put them to static, I get a NullPointerException.

I think that you need to use the Model-View-Control (MVC) pattern or an abbreviated version of it, perhaps one where you combine the view with the control since your program is small. I suggest that you have a separate model class, here this would likely be the SudokuBoard class, and then a view class, here probably the SwingSudokuBoard class. Your view's control methods (the ActionListeners) would call the model's `clearCells()` method. And don't use static *anything* here.

---

**Edit 3**
You ask:

> I assume something along with these lines. Model: SudokuBoard; View: SwingSudokuBoard; Control: SwingSudoKiller. How would that go about? I'd have the actionListener posted above in the control. How would the other classes look like? Since I assume the clear method lays in the Model which you want to be in SudokuBoard but it cant connect with the cells there.

I'm not a professional, nor have I received formal programming training, so theory is one of my weak points, but my interpretation of MVC is that the view listens to the model and updates itself when the model notifies it of changes and that the control listens to the view and responds to view changes by notifying the model. This precise pattern has variations and does not need to be followed exactly to the letter, but the key in all of this is to separate out in your code the separate concerns as much as possible so that "coupling" (the number of direct connections between classes) is low or "loose" and "cohesion" (code that deals with the same concerns) is high or "tight".

In your program, again I'd combine the view and control by using anonymous inner listeners just as you're doing. I'd have the view/control, which is the SwingSudokuBoard class, hold an instance of the SudokuBoard class as a class field, and have the view/control's anonymous listeners call methods on the SudokuBoard field. When I've done this sort of thing before, I've given the model support for being observed by giving it a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object as well as public `addPropertyChangeListener(...)` and `removePropertyChangeListener(...)` methods. Then the view could respond easily to changes in the model.

You state:

> Since I assume the clear method lays in the Model which you want to be in SudokuBoard but it cant connect with the cells there.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. The model *holds* the cells. Perhaps you don't mean the *logical* cells held by the model but rather the *displayed* cells held by the view. The view would add a listener to the model, and when notified of changes to the model, would ask the model for its data and use that to update the visualized cells.

---

**Edit 4**
For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class OverlySimpleModelView {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Model model = new Model();
      ViewControl viewControl = new ViewControl(model);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("OverlySimpleModelView");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(viewControl.getMainComponent());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class ViewControl {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JTextField number1Field = new JTextField(5);
   private JTextField number2Field = new JTextField(5);
   private JTextField productField = new JTextField(5);

   private Model model;

   public ViewControl(Model model) {
      this.model = model;
      model.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyPropChngListener());
      productField.setEditable(false);
      productField.setFocusable(false);

      mainPanel.add(number1Field);
      mainPanel.add(new JLabel(" * "));
      mainPanel.add(number2Field);
      mainPanel.add(new JLabel(" = "));
      mainPanel.add(productField);

      CalculateAction calculateAction = new CalculateAction("Calculate", KeyEvent.VK_C);
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(calculateAction));
      number1Field.addActionListener(calculateAction);
      number2Field.addActionListener(calculateAction);
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(new ClearAction("Clear", KeyEvent.VK_L)));
   }

   public JComponent getMainComponent() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private class MyPropChngListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         number1Field.setText(String.valueOf(model.getNumber1()));
         number2Field.setText(String.valueOf(model.getNumber2()));
         productField.setText(String.valueOf(model.calculateProduct()));
      }
   }

   private class CalculateAction extends AbstractAction {

      public CalculateAction(String text, int keyCode) {
         super(text);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, keyCode);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         try {
            double number1 = Double.parseDouble(number1Field.getText());
            double number2 = Double.parseDouble(number2Field.getText());

            model.setNumber1(number1);
            model.setNumber2(number2);
         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }

   private class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {

      public ClearAction(String text, int keyCode) {
         super(text);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, keyCode); // to allow buttons a mnemonic letter
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         model.clear();
      }
   }
}

class Model {
   public static final String NUMBERS_CHANGED = "numbers changed";
   private double number1 = 0.0;
   private double number2 = 0.0;
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport propChngSupport = 
         new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);



   public double getNumber1() {
      return number1;
   }

   public double getNumber2() {
      return number2;
   }

   public void clear() {
      setNumber1(0.0);
      setNumber2(0.0);
   }

   // make number1 field a "bound" property, one that notifies listeners if it is changed.
   public void setNumber1(double number1) {      
      Double oldValue = this.number1;
      Double newValue = number1;
      this.number1 = number1;
      propChngSupport.firePropertyChange(NUMBERS_CHANGED, oldValue , newValue);
   }

   // ditto for the number2 field
   public void setNumber2(double number2) {
      Double oldValue = this.number2;
      Double newValue = number2;
      this.number2 = number2;
      propChngSupport.firePropertyChange(NUMBERS_CHANGED, oldValue , newValue);
   }

   public double calculateProduct() {
      return number1 * number2;
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChngSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChngSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }
}
```

Or maybe better since it uses an array of numbers:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class OverlySimpleModelView {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Model model = new Model(5);
      ViewControl viewControl = new ViewControl(model);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("OverlySimpleModelView");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(viewControl.getMainComponent());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class ViewControl {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JTextField[] numberFields;
   private JTextField productField = new JTextField(5);

   private Model model;

   public ViewControl(Model model) {
      this.model = model;
      model.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyPropChngListener());
      productField.setEditable(false);
      productField.setFocusable(false);

      CalculateAction calculateAction = new CalculateAction("Calculate", KeyEvent.VK_C);

      numberFields = new JTextField[model.getNumberFieldsLength()];
      for (int i = 0; i < numberFields.length; i++) {
         numberFields[i] = new JTextField("0.0", 5);
         mainPanel.add(numberFields[i]);
         numberFields[i].addActionListener(calculateAction);

         if (i < numberFields.length - 1) {
            mainPanel.add(new JLabel(" + "));
         } else {
            mainPanel.add(new JLabel(" = "));
         }
      }
      mainPanel.add(productField);

      mainPanel.add(new JButton(calculateAction));
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(new ClearAction("Clear", KeyEvent.VK_L)));
   }

   public JComponent getMainComponent() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private class MyPropChngListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         for (int i = 0; i < numberFields.length; i++) {
            numberFields[i].setText(String.valueOf(model.getNumber(i)));
         }
         productField.setText(String.valueOf(model.calculateSum()));
      }
   }

   private class CalculateAction extends AbstractAction {

      public CalculateAction(String text, int keyCode) {
         super(text);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, keyCode);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         try {
            double[] numbers = new double[numberFields.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
               numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(numberFields[i].getText());
            }

            model.setNumbers(numbers);
         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }

   private class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {

      public ClearAction(String text, int keyCode) {
         super(text);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, keyCode); // to allow buttons a mnemonic letter
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         model.clear();
      }
   }
}

class Model {
   public static final String NUMBERS_CHANGED = "numbers changed";
   private double[] numbers;
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport propChngSupport = 
         new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);

   public Model(int length) {
      numbers = new double[length];
   }

   public void setNumbers(double[] numbers) {
      double[] oldValue = this.numbers;
      double[] newValue = numbers;
      this.numbers = numbers;
      propChngSupport.firePropertyChange(NUMBERS_CHANGED, oldValue , newValue);

   }

   public double calculateSum() {
      double sum = 0.0;
      for (double number : numbers) {
         sum += number;
      }
      return sum;
   }

   public double getNumber(int i) {
      return numbers[i];
   }

   public int getNumberFieldsLength() {
      return numbers.length;
   }

   public void clear() {
      double[] newNumbers = new double[numbers.length];
      setNumbers(newNumbers);
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChngSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChngSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I can completely understand you. You want me to have the clear method in the same class as I got the button, but then I cant call the cells. I added x.clearCells(); while x being what? My main class like, SwingSudokuBoard.clearCells(); ? Eitherway, if I add what you say the program complaints that it want the clearCells method and cells to be static. But if I put them to static, I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: @BobSmith: Please see **Edit 2** in answer above.

Comment: I assume something along with these lines. Model: SudokuBoard;
View: SwingSudokuBoard; Control: SwingSudoKiller. How would that go about? I'd have the actionListener posted above in the control. How would the other classes look like? Since I assume the clear method lays in the Model which you want to be in SudokuBoard but it cant connect with the cells there.

Comment: As a Java novice (any programming in general) there are some communicational issues. Honestly, I'm not completely sure what you mean with MVC. I haven't worked with that in prior. It sounds quite complicated for such a trivial task as reseting the game board. Id be very appreciative if you could collaborate with basically telling me what to do, code-wise. However, I am truly thankful for the help and effort you're putting in to this. Thanks